# Get read back vertices from ID2D1TransformedGeometry in DirectX

Tags: directx

I have a ID2D1TransformedGeometry that was created by transforming (via scale, translate, and rotate matrices) a ID2D1RectangleGeometry.

How can I get back the vertices of the ID2D1TransformedGeometry after the transformation of the rectangle done?